# WPF MVVM ListView Execute converter only when item visible

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, listviewitem

I have a huge observablecollection list with more than 100k elements.
In order to represent all these elements I've binded this observable to a listview, using a converter that create a graphic representation of each element.
When I show all these elements I run out of memory.

Is there a way to call the converter only on shown items in order to allocate memory only for these elements?

XAML

```
...    
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NodEntitiesList, Mode=TwoWay, 
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
               Converter={StaticResource ConvertToItemElement}, 
               IsAsync=True}" 
 Height="400">
</ListView>
...
```

CONVERTER CS

```
public object ConvertToItemElement(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;

    ObservableCollection<ItemVisualizer> obsIV = new ObservableCollection<ItemVisualizer>();

        // elemList is a list of line and data that could be visualized using an itemVisualizer
        foreach (elemList currElem in (ObservableCollection<elemList>)value)
        {
            ItemVisualizer tmp = new ItemVisualizer();
            tmp.Width = 100;
            tmp.Height = 100;
            currElem.Draw(ref tmp);

            obsIV.Add(tmp);
        }

        ListCollectionView ret = new ListCollectionView((ObservableCollection<ItemVisualizer>)obsIV);

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: This is a wrong approach. Don't create your UI in a `Converter`, but use a `DataTemplate` and virtualization (for huge items count).

Comment: The converter will only be invoked for visible items provided that you haven't disabled the UI virtualization somehow.

Comment: In theory the converter can be used also for things not related to strictly converting values, but keep in mind that if in your converter you modify the object that calls the converter you end up with an infinite recursion and you fill the stack. Dymanoid is right, your is not the correct approach to the problem, use binding and virtualization.